# rgba color mixing css

Tags: css, opacity, rgba, mixing

Trying to make a function that takes two RGBa values and results in a third. The first value will be of `opacity: 1` eg: `color: rbga((0,0,0,1);`and the second will be any opacity (set by the user). The goal then is to mix the two colors, as if you had COLOR A and then someone took a paint tool and went over it with a semi-transparent COLOR B.

Here is the effect I would like to create.

```
not code, just some values: 

(0,0,0,1) & (255,255,255,0.5)  = (128,128,128,1)

(255,0,0,1) & (255,255,255,0.5) = (225,128,128,1)

(0,255,255,1) & (255,255,255,0.5) = (128,255,128,1)

(0,0,255,1) & (255,255,255,0.5) = (128,128,255,1)

(81,188,187,1) & (252,0,255,0.5) = (167,94,221,1)

(81,188,187,1) & (102,192,110,0.5) = (92,190,148,1)

(81,188,187,1) & (255,228,0,0.5) = (168,208,93,1)
```

Here it is visually: 
(thought not the exact same example as the data above)

[image: Diagram of the hell I am talking about]

Here with values:

[image: example]

I will eventually be using javascript to create the function, but really what I need to figure out is the relationship between color 1 and color 2 in a way that I can put in code. I am just not good enough at math to figure this one out. So, here I am.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you get those values? If I do (81,188,187,1) & (102,192,110,.33) I get (8**7**,189,16**1**,1) and not (88,189,162,1). Or for the second one I get (1**2**8,201,125,1) instead of (138,201,125,1).

Comment: well the first one looks like a rounding thing. And the 2nd looks like I messed up retyping it. Sorry about that. I got them by doing the action in photoshop (as seen in the picture) and then reading the values with the photoshop eyedropper tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simple compositing :)

```
C = Ca*Aa*(1-Ab) + Cb*Ab
```

Where Ca is the component (Red, Green or Blue in turn) of Colour A, Cb is the component of Colour B, and Aa and Ab are the alpha values of A and B respectively (in this case, Aa will be 1).

So for (81,188,87,1) and (239,133,11,0.75), you get

```
81*1*(1-0.75) + 239*0.75 = 199.5
188*1*(1-0.75) + 133*0.75 = 146.75
87*1*(1-0.75) + 11*0.75 = 30
```

Resulting in (199,146,30,1)

(Alpha is calculated with A = Aa*(1-Ab) + Ab, but that will always be 1 if either alpha value is 1, which it is in your case)

Comment: what would it be if I had different opacity levels?